# div bottom float - css

Tags: css

I have 2 ids on my page as;

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

With styling;

```
#a {
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #9DBA6A;
}
#b {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #FF7E00;
}
```

I want to stick div b on div `a`'s bottom with some -ve margin or padding and I want to remain its position like that when div `a`'s height changes. The layout cannot be altered.

Here is a diagram;

[image]

You can see my fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/shP3D/)** and the complete layout [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7KTe6).

Comment: I may be missing the point, but on your example, removing the nesting from the div will solve this.  http://jsfiddle.net/shP3D/1/

Comment: Why do you want to have `#b` _inside_ `#a`?

Comment: is there any way to keep the nesting??

Comment: it is because here is my real problem in this layout http://jsfiddle.net/7KTe6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/23gCd/

I've kept your `<div id="b"></div>` inside your `<div id="a"></div>`. It will stay below `#a` no matter the height, but if `#b`'s height changes, you'd have to change it in the CSS.

### CSS

```
#a {
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #9DBA6A;
    position: relative;
}
#b {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #FF7E00;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
}
```

Adding the `position: relative` property to `#a` allows us to absolutely position `#b` relative to where `#a` is. So you can offset `#b` `-25px` from the bottom; if the height of `#b` changes, you'd have to change that offset as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in your fiddle and it worked:

```
#a {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #9DBA6A;
    position : relative;
}
#b {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #FF7E00;
    position : absolute;
    bottom : -25px;
}
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Mh, I don't know a solution for doing this with plain css if the height is not hardcoded. But if the height is hardcoded, just use `margin-top: 25px;` on `b`...

How would you want to change the height of `a`? Or would you remove the `height: 25px;` in your production code?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is setting `position:relative` on parent (that's not bad!) and `position:absolute` on child. The positions of child will be computed according to parent so `bottom:0` will stick it to bottom.

See http://jsfiddle.net/shP3D/12/